# Shift only one column in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

This is my DataFrame:

```
col1 col2

A   5
B   3
C   8
D   2
E   9
F   9
G   4
H   9
I   3
J   5
K   7
L   3
M   7
```

I want to shift column col2 by 5 units forward. Expected output:

```
col1 col2
A   na
B   na
C   na
D   na
E   na
F   5
G   3
H   8
I   2
J   9
K   9
L   4
M   9
na  3
na  5
na  7
na  3
na  7
```

I know about the existence of the shift method, but it shifts the whole DataFrame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do,

```
df['col2'] = df['col2'].shift(5)
```

You will get the following output

```
   col1  col2
0     A   NaN
1     B   NaN
2     C   NaN
3     D   NaN
4     E   NaN
5     F   5.0
6     G   3.0
7     H   8.0
8     I   2.0
9     J   9.0
10    K   9.0
11    L   4.0
12    M   9.0
```

But from the updated Q, I can see that the col1 should be extended as well. So do this instead,

```
df['col2'].index = df['col2'].index + 5
pd.concat([df['col1'], df['col2']], axis=1)

   col1  col2
0     A   NaN
1     B   NaN
2     C   NaN
3     D   NaN
4     E   NaN
5     F   5.0
6     G   3.0
7     H   8.0
8     I   2.0
9     J   9.0
10    K   9.0
11    L   4.0
12    M   9.0
13  NaN   3.0
14  NaN   5.0
15  NaN   7.0
16  NaN   3.0
17  NaN   7.0
```

Comment: what is the difference with df['col2'] = df['col2'].shift(5)?

Comment: With simple shift, you shift the column down and you loose the overflowed data. Here you retain them as mentioned in the question.

Comment: @IgorK. - I have updated my answer to show the difference

Answer (score 1):

Then:

```
df['col2'] = df['col2'].shift(5)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! it is very simple, but it is not described in documentation of  pandas.DataFrame.shift

Comment: Because you should be looking at [`Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html)

Comment: @QuangHoang I don't think this is the solution user expect